# Arcpy.CreateTable_management in Python toolbox not creating table in memory

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, table, python-toolbox, in-memory

The following creates a table in memory as expected when executed in the Python window [ArcGIS Pro 2.9, Windows 10]:
`arcpy.CreateTable_management('memory','dataTable')`

When I try to do the same thing in a Python toolbox tool (.pyt), the table does not appear to be created in memory (or anywhere else), although the call does not generate an error:

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = 'Create table in memory toolbox'
        self.tools = [CreateTable]

class CreateTable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = 'Create table in memory tool'
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        return None

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        arcpy.CreateTable_management('memory','dataTable')
        return
```

If I use a file GDB instead of memory, both approaches succeed.  Insights?

Comment: When I run your code, the table appears in memory. How are you determining it is not there?  Try arcpy.env.workspace = 'memory' and then arcpy.ListTables().

Comment: You might check if it exists first, and delete it or give it a different name. Otherwise you may receive an error. If arcpy.Exists("memory\\dataTable"): arcpy.Delete_management("memory\\dataTable")

Answer (score 1):

Shout out to Brennan: setting env.workspace appears to be the answer.  I had been using arcpy.Exists('dataTable') to determine whether the table had been created, but arcpy.ListTables() works too.

It's still curious that the behavior is different when executing the same command in the Python window - in that case not only is the table "found" by arcpy.Exists (without setting env.workspace), but it also immediately appears in the TOC as a "standalone table'.